# How to extract headings from Word files to Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, tableofcontents

I have hundreds of Word files (docx) which each have various headings, defined as Heading 1, Heading 2, Heading 3, etc. Each of these files has a table of contents which correspond to the headings.
I want to extract each heading from each of these files into an Excel workbook to build a database.

My first attempt was to extract the headings from a single Word document into an Excel workbook. I found code online to extract headings from Word to Outlook, and also separate code to extract headings from Word to a new Word file.
I haven't been able to adapt either of these.

How do I extract headings from a single Word file to Excel? I will then try to work out further steps.

**Word to Outlook**

```vb
Sub CopyHeadingsIntoOutlookMail()
    Dim objOutlookApp, objMail As Object
    Dim objMailDocument As Word.Document
    Dim objMailRange As Word.Range
    Dim varHeadings As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim strText As String
    Dim nLongDiff As Integer

    'Create a new Outlook email
    Set objOutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objMail = objOutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    objMail.Display
    Set objMailDocument = objMail.GetInspector.WordEditor
    Set objMailRange = objMailDocument.Range(0, 0)
 
    'Get the headings of the current Word document
    varHeadings = ActiveDocument.GetCrossReferenceItems(wdRefTypeHeading)

    For i = LBound(varHeadings) To UBound(varHeadings)
        strText = Trim(varHeadings(i))
 
        'Get the heading level
        nLongDiff = Len(RTrim$(CStr(varHeadings(i)))) - Len(Trim(CStr(varHeadings(i))))
        nHeadingLevel = (nLongDiff / 2) + 1
 
        'Insert the heading into the Outlook mail
        With objMailRange
            .InsertAfter strText & vbNewLine
            .Style = "Heading " & nHeadingLevel
            .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

**Word to Word**

```vb
Public Sub CreateOutline()
    Dim docOutline As Word.Document
    Dim docSource As Word.Document
    Dim rng As Word.Range
    
    Dim astrHeadings As Variant
    Dim strText As String
    Dim intLevel As Integer
    Dim intItem As Integer
        
    Set docSource = ActiveDocument
    Set docOutline = Documents.Add
    
    ' Content returns only the
    ' main body of the document, not
    ' the headers and footer.
    Set rng = docOutline.Content
    astrHeadings = _
     docSource.GetCrossReferenceItems(wdRefTypeHeading)
    
    For intItem = LBound(astrHeadings) To UBound(astrHeadings)
        ' Get the text and the level.
        strText = Trim$(astrHeadings(intItem))
        intLevel = GetLevel(CStr(astrHeadings(intItem)))
        
        ' Add the text to the document.
        rng.InsertAfter strText & vbNewLine
        
        ' Set the style of the selected range and
        ' then collapse the range for the next entry.
        rng.Style = "Heading " & intLevel
        rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    Next intItem
End Sub

Private Function GetLevel(strItem As String) As Integer
    ' Return the heading level of a header from the
    ' array returned by Word.
    
    ' The number of leading spaces indicates the
    ' outline level (2 spaces per level: H1 has
    ' 0 spaces, H2 has 2 spaces, H3 has 4 spaces.
        
    Dim strTemp As String
    Dim strOriginal As String
    Dim intDiff As Integer
    
    ' Get rid of all trailing spaces.
    strOriginal = RTrim$(strItem)
    
    ' Trim leading spaces, and then compare with
    ' the original.
    strTemp = LTrim$(strOriginal)
    
    ' Subtract to find the number of
    ' leading spaces in the original string.
    intDiff = Len(strOriginal) - Len(strTemp)
    GetLevel = (intDiff / 2) + 1
End Function
```

Comment: I suspect that you will want to start this from Excel. You need to decide how you are going to store the data you get in Excel. How many rows per document? As many as there are headings? Are you going to have different columns for different heading levels?

Comment: You would find code that cycles through all documents in a particular folder for find and replace at the MVP FAQ site. That could be adopted for your task once you have the code to extract and store the headings. https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/BatchFR.htm

Comment: Note, macropod's macro is an Excel macro. It does not extract the headings, as such, but rather the Table of Contents. If the TOCs are based on the headings you want, it should work well for you. *(Tables of contents are based on Headings 1-3 by default but can be based on other things.)*

Comment: Dear Charles, thank you very much for taking the time to answer this. Macropod below has kindly provided me with the full code so I am good to go.

Comment: Sorry I saw your last comment after submitting my one. Perhaps ideally it would ignore any files without tables of contents without breaking the cycle, or simply extract the headings. However it certainly will hit a critical mass of files to help build the database

Comment: «It does not extract the headings, as such, but rather the Table of Contents.» A pointless criticism given that the OP said «Each of these files also has a table of contents which correspond to the headings».

Comment: If that turns out to leave out too many files, or if information you need in the files is not contained in the TOC, you could change the code to recreate the TOC to show only headings and to the appropriate level (and then close the source doc without saving). I expect that macropod's work will get you what you want, though. It all depends on how the source documents are set up. The macro is already set to skip documents without a TOC.

Comment: The macro *does not* skip documents without a TOC. It lists them without any TOC entries.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following Excel macro. When you run it, simply select the folder to process.

```
Sub GetTOCHeadings()
'Note: this code requires a reference to the Word object model.
'See under the VBE's Tools|References.
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim wdDoc As Word.Document, wdRng As Word.Range, wdPara As Word.Paragraph
Dim strFolder As String, strFile As String
Dim WkSht As Worksheet, i As Long, j As Long
strFolder = GetFolder
If strFolder = "" Then Exit Sub
Dim wdApp As New Word.Application
Set WkSht = ActiveSheet
i = WkSht.Cells(WkSht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
wdApp.WordBasic.DisableAutoMacros
wdApp.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone
strFile = Dir(strFolder & "\*.doc", vbNormal)
While strFile <> ""
  i = i + 1
  Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(Filename:=strFolder & "\" & strFile, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)
  With wdDoc
    j = 1: WkSht.Cells(i, j) = strFile
    If .TablesOfContents.Count > 0 Then
      With .TablesOfContents(1)
        .IncludePageNumbers = False
        .Update
        Set wdRng = .Range
      End With
      With wdRng
        .Fields(1).Unlink
        For Each wdPara In .Paragraphs
          j = j + 1
          WkSht.Cells(i, j).Value = Replace(wdPara.Range.Text, vbTab, " ")
        Next
      End With
    End If
    .Close SaveChanges:=False
  End With
  strFile = Dir()
Wend
wdApp.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsAll
wdApp.Quit
Set wdDoc = Nothing: Set wdApp = Nothing: Set WkSht = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
 
Function GetFolder() As String
    Dim oFolder As Object
    GetFolder = ""
    Set oFolder = CreateObject("Shell.Application").BrowseForFolder(0, "Choose a folder", 0)
    If (Not oFolder Is Nothing) Then GetFolder = oFolder.Items.Item.Path
    Set oFolder = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Macropod, this is absolutely masterful work. Thank you so much for taking the time to do write this, it helps me immensely. I noticed that stalls if a document has the table of contents removed (says it is waiting for an OLE action) but that shouldn't really be a problem for me.

Comment: Not a problem because they should all have a TOC. I think I will amend the macro slightly to have the headings appear vertically in column B, rather than horizontally across a row, but these are things that I should be able to manage through some playing around. It's great that it also shows the file name that it extracts from. I guess when I run it in the folder with the hundreds of documents I should probably allow it some time to complete it's task without interfering. Anyway, thank you once more.

Comment: The lack of a Table of Contents shouldn't have any impact, as the code tests whether the document has one (If .TablesOfContents.Count > 0 Then) before trying to process it. The only difference you should see is that there are no Table of Contents entries for such documents. That's how it works in my testing. The only reason for stalling I can see is if the document has links to other documents/files that need updating. It would also fall over if the document is protected (e.g. password to open or for 'Filling in Forms')

Comment: «I think I will amend the macro slightly to have the headings appear vertically in column B, rather than horizontally across a row» DATABASE structures in Excel ordinarily require all data for a given record (i.e. file) to appear on the same row, which is why I coded the macro that way.

Comment: Hi. I've run more tests and indeed if there is no TOC then simply the row is not populated. I'm not entirely sure why I hit that OLE error then on my first test (I copied the same file 3 times and amended the headings contents in each, and it got stuck on the second file - maybe because I purposefully didn't update the TOC after changing the headings in this second file). Regarding row vs columns population, what you say makes sense. My original thinking was that it would be easier to filter entries if they were all in the same column but CTRL + F essentially does the same job. Thank you.